# Apache Http Components - setting cookie

Tags: java, apache, http, cookies

I am using Apache Http Components to set a cookie for localhost. When I return the cookie I get the output:

```
[version: 0][name: testCookie][value: test][domain: http://localhost:9090/][path: /][expiry: Mon Aug 07 19:11:56 BST 2017]
```

which makes me think the cookie has been set, but when I check in chrome to see if it's in chrome://settings/cookies there's nothing there.

```
    public Object makeCookie(String p) throws IOException, MalformedCookieException{

        Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance();
        myCal.set(2017, 07, 07);
        Date theDate = myCal.getTime();
        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("testCookie",p);
        // Set effective domain and path attributes
        cookie.setDomain("http://localhost:9090/");
        cookie.setPath("/");
        cookie.setExpiryDate(theDate);
        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);
        // Set attributes exactly as sent by the server
        cookie.setAttribute(ClientCookie.PATH_ATTR, "/");
        cookie.setAttribute(ClientCookie.DOMAIN_ATTR, "http://localhost:9090/");
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setDefaultCookieStore(cookieStore)
                .build();

        return cookie;
}
```

I've been stuck on this for hours and I just can't figure out why it's not being stored in the browser

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code just creates the client cookie storage but doesn't send created cookie anywhere.

According to Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie), "cookie  is a small piece of data sent from a website and stored in the user's web browser while the user is browsing."

HttpClient is not the entity you need, because it's a client, not server. You can use it to execute HTTP requests to websites, but it's just consumer, like your local browser. So even if you specify cookie storage on your client, it has no effect on your local browser. Server (say website) is the guy who send cookies to clients.

The HttpClient in your code and your local browser are 2 independent clients. They can receive cookies from websites, but these 2 clients are not websites themselves. That's why `CloseableHttpClient` object is useless here. Moreover, you don't use it in your code. Also it might leak the memory, since you don't close it properly.

As I already said, your code just creates the cookie. So you need to send created cookie to the client. You even don't need to create the cookie storage, you can just create cookie itself.

So you need to create a simple web application using Servlet API. Then you can attach the created cookie to the `HttpServlerResponse` object in the desired HTTP request handler. You can do something like this (SpringMVC example):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
    public String index(HttpServletResponse response) {
        // no prepareCookie implementation here
        Cookie myCookie = prepareCookie();
        response.addCookie(myCookie);
        // view name
        return "index";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thing is, I'm using nanohttp (a lightwight server), who's cookies don't provide a method to set the path. That's why I don't want to use a servlet API and am trying to find an alternative way to pass cookies